# Datalist suggestions on input in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Is there a way to get the javascript-less suggestions through datalist:

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." list="item-list">
<datalist id="item-list">
    <option value="pid1">item1</option>
    <option value="pid2">item2</option>
    <option value="pid3">item3</option>
</datalist>
```

To work in Firefox? It works great in Chrome

Comment: Works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNyU6.png (you need to click the input box again after focusing for some reason)

Comment: @SuperStormer Ah yeah if you click twice it does work. Any way around that?